# How to extract string between a pattern and a position from the pattern with Tshark and sed

Tags: regex, sed, tshark

The problem I have cosist in:
With Tshark and sed I can obtain the rtp-stream in hex dump. Is it possible to obtain only the byte between a pattern and a position after the pattern.
I provide an example:
In cmd...
Tshark -x -r "C:whatever\file.pcap" -Y "rtp and frame.len==1200" | sed ¿¿¿???

How should I write the regular expression in sed?
The pattern is '47 00 11 1*' and the position after the pattern is two and three.
For instance: 09 9f 5a 47 00 11 18 ce ff ff. The point would be obtain 'ce'.

Thank you very much for you assistance!

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, the focus of this question is regex, and sed is one tool that uses regex (other bash ones being grep and awk). sed also differs between linux and macos; here I'm using GNU sed which you are likely using as well.

We'll use sed as that is part of the question statement.

#### The Regex

This is your regex: `47 00 11 1..(..)`. The `47 00 11 1` matches these characters exactly. `..` will match any 2 characters. `(..)` will capture the 2 characters after, whatever they are. The parentheses form the capturing group and are important because they return only the string we care about.

To play around with regexes, I recommend using regex101. You can explore this specific regex and test case on regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/VALrAL/1).

#### Piping to Sed

Your question uses sed, so this would be

```sh
bash-5.0$ echo "09 9f 5a 47 00 11 18 ce ff ff" | sed -n 's/.*47 00 11 1..\(..\).*/\1/p'
ce
```

Here, the regex is the same apart from sed requirements:

- `.*`: .* matches any number of characters. Adding it to beginning and end will match the string exactly.
- `\(`,`\)`: sed requires escaping parentheses to denote capture groups

Other components are as follows:

- `-n`: Be quiet about internal processing of pattern
- `s/`: Substitute the string provided with the capture group
- `\1`: Replace with capture group 1
- `/p`: Print the result (used in conjunction with `/s` at the beginning)

**Note**: Many languages like Perl support a regex standard called [PCRE](https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/pcre) (**P**erl **C**ompatible **R**egular **E**xpressions), which is easier to use than sed syntax. In my experience, using Perl or Python inline for regexes makes your life easier than using sed (or grep or awk).